# SQL CASE that matches value or uses LIKE '%'

Tags: sql, case, where-clause, sql-null

I'm trying to do a wildcard retrieve if a defined variable is blank. But I can't figure out the correct syntax.

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE customers = CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(@customerID, '') = '' THEN LIKE '%'
    ELSE @customerID
END
```

Comment: What database is it?

Comment: Sorry to be unhelpful, but I'm not sure. This code is executing through a third party software.

Comment: A [mcve] would make things much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as this:

```
WHERE customers = NULLIF(@customerID, '') OR NULLIF(@customerID, '') IS NULL
```

The expression `NULLIF(x, '')` will convert `''` to null. Then we take advantage of how null comparison works:

- If `@customerID` is not null then first condition will be true only for exact match
- If `@customerID` is null then first condition will be false (nothing equals null) but second condition will be true for all rows

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0c2040f7731e200b92a1d0e1f33f890d)

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear. 

The variable to be blank is the @customerID. It should then retrieve all customers in that case.

WHEN CustomerID = '' THEN *fetch all customers ELSE

*fetch customers with customerID* END

Your solution attempts to retrieve any entries that don't have a customerID.

Comment: It does exactly that (read the two bullet points). But this query assumes that blank means null. If you want to consider `''` as blank then one tweak is needed. What rdbms are you using?

Comment: I'm unsure of the rdbms as the SQL is run through a third party software.

I've tried out your solution and it retrieves multiple customer IDs both when customerID is populated and also when blank. I appreciate the link to fiddle, but now I'm more confused why I'm experiencing different behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot answer any further than this. This answer is based on how standard (ANSI) SQL works.

Comment: Hi again,

This ended up being exactly what I needed, and the error was due to some malformed data in our test environment.

Thanks a lot for taking the time to respond and explain it all to me. You've been a great help!

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply put it like this

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE customers = ISNULL(@customerID,'') OR (ISNULL(@customerID,'') = '')
```

This should work because if the first condition was met, it will select the specific customer id. Otherwise, if the customer id is null,it will select all data because of this condition below:

```
(ISNULL(@customerID,'') = ''
```

If NULL, '' = '' will be true.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this solution hasn't worked for me as I receive an error when inputting a blank value for customerID.